# wheel scroll not working in ie 11 and Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, mousewheel

I'm using scroll bar for a drop box.From that I can able to scroll by click and drag scroll bar.But scroll bar not working in wheel scroll.I am facing this problem in IE 11 browser and Firefox browser,in chrome browser it is working fine.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: post the markup for the `select` element,or at least post a screen shot of the scroll bar while the dropdown is opend.

Comment: [Check This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8Je2/8/)_italic_ @KeesSonnema . some times working and sometimes wheel scrolling failed. Kindly check this in all three browser.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. All is working here in Firefox and IE. Only thing I changed is `#content {
  height:10px;
}` to `#content {
  height:20px;
}`

Comment: Yeah it's working in fiddle.Not working in my project.By the way thanks for your effort @KeesSonnema

Comment: No problem. If you have a live example, show us :)